# WebRTC OnClick Button is not calling the necessary Function

Tags: javascript, webrtc

All,

Following a webrtc tutorial for setting up a peer to peer webpage I ran into an issue with the button |btnGoRoom.onclick = function ()|, when selected it does not do anything.. I've parsed the code to clean up any errors in typing and am at a lose.. any advice? I can provide more information on the setup done or other file if need be. This is my first attempt at writing javascript, a bit new to the options for buttons, thanks for any help in advance!

```html
// here we get a reference to the webpage elements
var divSelectRoom = document.getElementById("selectRoom");
var divConsultingRoom = document.getElementById("consultingRoom");
var inputRoomNumber = document.getElementById("roomNumber");
var btnGoRoom = document.getElementById("goRoom");
var localVideo = document.getElementById("localVideo");
var remoteVideo = document.getElementById("remoteVideo");

// these are the global variables
var roomNumber;
var localStream;
var remoteStream;
var rtcPeerConnection;

// these are the STUN servers
var iceServers = {
 'iceServers': [
 {'url':stun:stun.services.mozilla.com'},
 {'url':'stun.stun.i.google.com:19302'}
]
}
var streamConstraints = { audio: true, video: true };
var isCaller;

// here we connect to the socket.io server. We will create it later.
var socket = io();

// here we add a click event to the button
btnGoRoom.onclick = function () {
 if (inputRoomNumber.value === "){
 alert("Please type a room number")
} else {
 roomNumber = inputRoomNumber.value; //we take the value from the element
 socket.emit('create or join', roomNumber); //we send a message to the server
 divSelectRoom.style = "display: none;"; //hide selectRoom div
 divConsultingRoom.style = "display: block;"; //show consultingRoom div
 }
};

// when server emits created
socket.on('created', function (room) {
 //caller gets user media devices with defined constraints
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(streamConstraints).then(function (stream){
  localStream = stream; //sets local stream to a variable
  localVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream); //shows stream to user
  isCaller = true; //sets current user as caller
 }).catch(function (err) {
  console.log('An error ocurred when accessing media devices');
 });
});

// when server emits joined
socket.on('joined', functon (room) {
 //callee gets user media devices
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(streamConstraints).then(function (stream){
  localStream = stream; //sets local stream to a variable
  localVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream); //shows stream to user
  socket.emit('ready',roomNumber); //sends message to server
 }).catch(function (err) {
  console.log('An error ocurred when accessing media devices');
 });
});

// when server emits ready
socket.on('ready', function () {
 if(isCaller){
  // Creates an RTCPeerConnection Object
  rtcPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(iceServers);
 
  // Adds event listeners to the newly created oject
  rtcPeerConnection.onicecandidate = onIceCandidate;
  rtcPeerConnection.onaddStream = onAddStream;

  // Adds the current local stream to the object
  rtcPeerConnection.addStream(localStream);

  // Prepares an Offer
  rtcPeerConnection.createOffer(setLocalAndOffer,function(e){console.log(e)});
 }
});

// When servers emits offer
socket.on('offer', function (event){
 if(!isCaller){
  // Creates an RTCPeerConnection object
  rtcPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(iceServers);

  // Adds event listeners to the newly created object
  rtcPeerConnection.onicecandidate = onIceCandidate;
  rtcPeerConnection.onaddstream = onAddStream;

  // Adds the current local stream to the object
  rtcPeerConnection.addStream(localStream);
  
  // Stores the offer as remote description
  rtcPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(event));

  // Prepares an Answer
  rtcPeerConnection.createAnswer(setLocalAndAnswer, function(e){console.log(e)});
 }
});

// When server emits answer
socket.on('answer', function (event){
 // Stores it as a remote description
 rtcPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(event));
});

// When server emits candidate
socket.on('candidate', function (event) {
 // Creates a candidate object
 var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({
  sdpMLineIndex: event.label,
  candidate: event.candidate
 });

 // Stores candidate
 rtcPeerConneciton.addIceCandidate(candidate);
});

// When a user receives the other user's video and audio stream
function onAddStream(event) {
 remoteVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
 remoteStream = event.stream;
}

// These are the functions referenced before as listeners for the peer connection
// Sends a candidate message to server
function onIceCandidate(event) {
 if (event.candidate) {
  console.log('sending ice candidate');
  socket.emit('candidate',{
   type: 'candidate',
   lable: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
   id: event.candidate.sdpMid,
   candidate: event.candidate.candidate,
   room: roomNumber
  })
 }
}

// Stores offer and sends message to server
function setLocalAndOffer(sessionDescription) {
 rtcPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
 socket.emit('offer',{
  type: 'offer',
  sdp: sessionDescription,
  room: roomNumber
 });
}

// Stores answer and sends message to server
function setLocalAndAnswer(sessionDescription){
 rtcPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
 socket.emit('answer',{
  type: 'answer',
  sdp: sessionDescription,
  room: roomNumber
 });
}
```

Comment: unclosed string on iine 18:`'url': stun: stun.services.mozilla.com '}, {`

Comment: another unclosed string `if (inputRoomNumber.value === "){` that should be `''` or `""` not `"`

Comment: `socket.on('joined', functon(room) {` ... should be `socket.on('joined', function(room) {`

Comment: of course, you should've seen these errors in the browsers developer tools console - so far the problem is simple typos

Comment: Oh wow I can’t believe I missed that much after reviewing it, I’m definitely gonna use the dev console to make thing easier, thank you very much for that tip and your help! I’ll try that out in the morning!

Comment: another "cheat" is using jsfiddle.net - you can paste code in there, tidy it up, and review errors (little red and yellow dots next to your code) - that's how I fond those 3 typos